# Esperar una respuesta para continuar en Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Soy nuevo en angular y espero que me puedan ayudar.
Estoy haciendo la parte del login de una webapp.

Tengo este codigo, en la primera parte envio el usuario y contraseña a la api y la api me devuelve  en la variaable **data2** un "Sesion iniciada", si todo coincide, y si no, quiero que se vaya al else, en el que tengo el codigo para que se muestre una ventana con el error.

```
iniciar():void{
    this.apiService.login(this.login).subscribe(response => {this.data2 = response;});
    console.log(this.data2);
    if(this.data2 == 'Sesion iniciada') {
      
    }
    else {
      this.alerts.push({
        id: 4,
        type: 'danger',
        strong: 'Error,',
        message: this.data2,
        icon: 'objects_support-17'
      });
      this.backup = this.alerts.map((alert: IAlert) => Object.assign({}, alert));
    }
  }
```

El problema es que cuando se ejecuta no da tiempo a que la api devuelva la respuesta y siempre se va al else.
Habra alguna forma de que espere a la respuesta antes de continuar con el codigo?

Comment: Probaste con [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/funcion_asincrona) para ello?

Comment: Cómo sería eso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que tienes el código que quieres ejecutar fuera del *.subscribe*, este ya se encarga de esperar a que la respuesta del lado del servidor se complete, dado que tu servicio *.login* devuelve un observable puesto que son operaciones asíncronas. Revisa esta [liga](https://academia-binaria.com/comunicaciones-http-en-Angular/) de referencia.

En todo caso, tu código debería funcionar de la siguiente manera:

```
iniciar():void{
    this.apiService.login(this.login).subscribe(response => {
      this.data2 = response;
      console.log(this.data2);
      if(this.data2 == 'Sesion iniciada') {
      
      } else {
        this.alerts.push({
          id: 4,
          type: 'danger',
          strong: 'Error,',
          message: this.data2,
          icon: 'objects_support-17'
        });
      this.backup = this.alerts.map((alert: IAlert) => Object.assign({}, alert));
     }
   });
}
```